# Доработка обратной связи в telegram-боте на python

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Есть код(спасибо рунету), который позволяет вести диалог через бота админу и юзеру. Проблема в том, что если 2 юзера сразу пишут, ответ админа идет только последнему, первый остается без ответа(проверил на 3 телефонах: админ, юзер 1, юезр2). Привязки к юзерам нет.
Вообще, пытаюсь еще догнать как сделать 2 кнопки и привязать их к 2 админам(каждому своя), чтобы при нажатии на 1 кнопку юзер1 отправлял сообщения только админу1, а при нажатии на 2 сообщения только админу2. Ну или хотя бы вариант чтобы разные юзеры вели свою беседу с админом.
Есть очень много документации к Aiogram, но так вышло, что выбрана была telebot, отступать не вариант(aiogram без сомнений на очереди, но сейчас нужно выжать все что можно из телебота).
Надеюсь на помощь...

```
import telebot
token=''
bot=telebot.TeleBot(token)

adm = 1111111111  # Telegram id


@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def send_welcome(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите свое сообщение')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, forward_adm)


def forward_adm(message):
    print('forward_adm')
    print(message.chat.id)
    bot.send_message(adm, '{}'.format(message.text))
    forward_usr(message)


def forward_usr(message):
    print('forward_usr')
    print(message.chat.id)
    global usr_id
    usr_id = message.chat.id

    msg = bot.send_message(adm, 'Введите свой ответ')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, forward_usr_1)


def forward_usr_1(message):
    print('forward_usr_1')
    print(message.chat.id)
    bot.send_message(usr_id, '{}'.format(message.text))



bot.infinity_polling()
```

Comment: Вот, пожалуйста, документация по [telebot](https://pytba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Диалог между пользователем и одним из операторов через телеграм бота](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1478940/%d0%94%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0)

Comment: в том коде ругается на AsyncTeleBot.